# Perl Net::FTP and non-ASCII (UTF8) characters in file names

Tags: perl, ftp, perl-module

I am using Net::FTP to access a PVR (satellite receiver) and retrieve recorded video files. Obtaining a list of all files using the `dir()` subroutine works fine, however if file names contain non-ASCII (UTF8) characters, calls to `mtdm()` and `get()` fail for these files. Here's an example (containing a german "umlaut"):

```
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x253d000)>>> MDTM /DataFiles/Kommissar Beck ~ Tödliche Kunst.rec
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x253d000)<<< 550 Can't access /DataFiles/Kommissar Beck ~ Tödliche Kunst.rec
```

File names only containing ASCII characters work well. Accessing files with non-ASCII characters through other FTP software works well too.

Does anyone have an idea how I can possibly make this work? Obviously I cannot simply avoid "umlauts" in file names.

Comment: Most OSs and Perl consider file names to be arbitrary bytes, so the question is: What bytes did you pass to Net::FTP? What bytes form the file names on the system in question? Data::Dumper with `local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` will help provide this data to us.

Comment: Are you sure it's utf-8? Maybe it's just latin-1.

Comment: I pass in what I receive from `dir()`. Following your suggestion I have checked that both the data I receive from `dir()` and the file name I use with `mdtm()` is UTF8 encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ikegame and Slaven Rezic, your suggestions helped me solve the problem.

To sum it up: it is a bug in Topfield SRP2100's FTP implementation. The problem is not Perl or Net::FTP related. The MDTM command does not accept non-ASCII characters while the RETR command does. I checked with a network sniffer that my code and Net::FTP was doing everything right. All filenames sent in FTP commands were 100% correct.

I worked around the problem by parsing the date shown in the output of `dir()` instead of using MDTM for non-ASCII file names -- not a nice solution but it worked.